# Questions about descriptive measures and probability

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a binomial random with $n = 10$ and $p = 0.4$, what is the probability that $X$ is greater than $2$? (3dp)

As we know the

① $C(n, x)=\dfrac{n！}{x！\cdot（n-x）！}$

② $P(x)= \left[\dfrac{n!}{x!\cdot(n-x)!}\right] \cdot p^x \cdot (1-p)^{n-x}$

Comment: It would be easier to calculate the probability $1 - P(X < 2)$

Comment: $\begin{align}\Pr(X > 2) & = 1 - P(x\leq 2) \\ & = 1-(P(0)+P(1)+P(2))\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

From ${\large \bigcirc\!\!\!\!\!}{2\;}$ we know $P(x) = \frac{n!\, p^x\,(1-p)^{n-x}}{x!\,(n-x)!}$ so...

$\begin{align}
\Pr(X>2) & = 1 - \Pr(X\leq 2)
\\ & = 1 - P(0) - P(1) - P(2)
\\ & = 1 - \frac{n!\, p^0\,(1-p)^{n-0}}{0!\,(n-0)!}- \frac{n!\, p^1\,(1-p)^{n-1}}{1!\,(n-1)!} - \frac{n!\, p^2\,(1-p)^{n-2}}{2!\,(n-2)!}
\\ & \ddots
\end{align}$

So if we know what $n$ and $p$ are then ...